# Saving recursive function results as array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, recursion, permutation

I'm looking into recursive functions (not from libraries) for creating permutations with repetitions and I found some code that I feel like I understand. I'd like to take it a step further and try saving it as a Numpy array, but I can't seem to figure out where to "return" in order to save the permutations into an array. Please advise.

```
def _permutation_repeat(text, prefix, n, k):
    if k == 0: 
        print(prefix)
        return

    for i in range(n):
        new_prefix = prefix + text[i] 
        _permutation_repeat(text, new_prefix, n, k-1)


def permutation_repeat(text, k):
    _permutation_repeat(text, "", len(text), k)


permutation_repeat("ABCD", 2)
```

Code from: https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/coding-interview/permutations-with-repeating-characters/

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
def _permutation_repeat(text, prefix, n, k):
    if k == 0: 
        print(prefix)
        return np.array([prefix])

    arr = np.array([])

    for i in range(n):
        new_prefix = prefix + text[i] 
        new_arr = _permutation_repeat(text, new_prefix, n, k-1)
        arr = np.concatenate([arr, new_arr])

    return arr

def permutation_repeat(text, k):
    return _permutation_repeat(text, "", len(text), k)


permutation_repeat("ABCD", 2)
```

Comment: I see where you're going with this. However, I get an error in line 10; arr = np.array(); TypeError: array() missing required argument 'object' (pos 1)

Comment: Edit. That line should be `np.array([])`

Comment: For some reason, I get the same output.

Comment: Oh! When I removed print(prefix) from the code with your suggestions, my output became an array whose elements were the permutations. Thank you!!